# Laravel mysql query to return notifications

Tags: mysql, laravel

```php
$groups = DB::table('user_hobbies')
    ->where('user_id', '==', $user->id)
    ->leftJoin('hobbies', 'hobbies.id', '=', 'user_hobbies.hobby_id')
    ->where('hobbies.admin_id', '!=', $user->id)
    ->select('hobbies.*')
    ->orderBy('name', 'ASC')
    ->get();

if ($groups->count() > 0) {
    foreach ($groups as $group){
        $name = DB::table('user_hobbies')
            ->where('id', $group->admin_id)
            ->value('first_name');
 
        $avatar = DB::table('user_hobbies')
            ->where('id', $group->admin_id)
            ->value('avatar_location');

        $notifications[] = [
            'url' => url('/groups/'),
            'icon' => 'fas fa-comment',
            'text' => $name.' added you to a new group!',
            'img' => url('/storage/'.$avatar)
        ];
    }
}
```

Hey guys, beginner here.. I am trying to add a notification for when an admin adds user to a new group, I'm working with this code to try to return the notification but nothing is appearing in the notifications, its empty. Is there an error? I can't quite seem to understand the problem since I'm following a similar function which does work when returning comment notifications. Any idea where I'm going wrong or where I should look next?

Comment: `where('user_id', '==', $user->id)` is weird. To my knowledge, `==`  is not a valid MySQL operator. Also, you're querying the same table **a lot** of times. 1 in the `$groups` query and  `$groups->count()` times later. That can't be good. Since it's the same table, this probably can be solved with a single query.

Comment: It's even more queries. It's 1 + (`$groups->count()` x 2) times.

Comment: Without knowing the structure of your tables, I can't really help much.

Comment: In case you didn't know, Laravel has [Notifications](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the results you want (at least in the `$notifications` array with a single query.

Based on the little information I have, this should work.

```php
$groups = DB::table('user_hobbies')
    ->select('first_name', 'avatar_location')
    ->whereIn('id', function ($sub) use ($user) {
        return $sub->select('hobbies.admin_id')
            ->from('user_hobbies')
            ->leftJoin('hobbies', 'hobbies.id', 'user_hobbies.hobby_id')
            ->where('user_id', $user->id)            
            ->where('hobbies.admin_id', '!=', $user->id);
    })
    ->get();

$notifications = $groups->map(function ($group) {
    return [
        'url' => url('/groups/'),
        'icon' => 'fas fa-comment',
        'text' => $group->first_name.' added you to a new group!',
        'img' => url('/storage/'.$group->avatar_location)
    ];
})
->all();
```

Comment: This works! thank you very much, but the $group->first_name and $group->avatar_location returns an error. I'll find those names somehow! beginner question but.. may I ask the purpose of creating a function inside the query?

Comment: `whereIn('id', function ($sub) use ($user) {})` is a way to make a subquery. Something that compiles to `WHERE id IN (  SELECT .... )`